# Using PHP's getlastmod() and SSI to make dynamic footer?

Tags: php, web, ssi

printI've been trying to create a standard footer for all of the pages on my website.  To test this, I've created a minimal file, like so:

```
<html>
<body>
This is a test file.
<!--#include virtual="/footer.php" -->
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I have in footer.php:

```
<div id="footer">
What a lovely footer! <br />
<?php
    echo "Last modified: " . date("d F Y H:i:s.", getlastmod()); 
?>
</div>
```

However, the last modify date displayed is that of footer.php

How could I make it such that it prints the last modify date of the file that includes it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `filemtime($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`, however I'm not sure how server-side includes work, so this might also produce the modification time of the footer file.

Comment: I tried this, and the filemtime call returns a stat failed error.  Google says that this is because the file doesn't exist?  I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: Having it just print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] gives the location of footer.php, even when included.

Answer (score 0):

do you have to use server-side includes?
If you include the footer.php using php:

```
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

it gives the last modified date of the including file (not the footer file)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<?php echo "last modified: ".filemtime($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
```